# java : constant expression required. switch satement use some constants which are defined in another calss

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

In the switch statement,I use some constants which are defined in another class.
The IDE tell me  `constant expression required`.

I am writing an Android app, and in the MainActivity I write like this:

```
private static final int HOMEFRAGMENTINDEX = 0;
private static final int MESSAGEFRAGMENTINDEX = 1;
private static final int SNSFRAGMENTINDEX = 2;
private static final int DISCOVERYFRAGMENTINDEX = 3;
private static final int MINEFRAGMENTINDEX = 4;

public static int getHomefragmentindex() {
    return HOMEFRAGMENTINDEX;
}

public static int getMessagefragmentindex() {
    return MESSAGEFRAGMENTINDEX;
}

public static int getSnsfragmentindex() {
    return SNSFRAGMENTINDEX;
}

public static int getDiscoveryfragmentindex() {
    return DISCOVERYFRAGMENTINDEX;
}

public static int getMinefragmentindex() {
    return MINEFRAGMENTINDEX;
}
```

and in another class I use the switch statement like this:

```
final int homeFragmentIndex = MainActivity.getHomefragmentindex();
final int messageFramentIndex = MainActivity.getMessagefragmentindex();
final int snsFragmentIndex = MainActivity.getSnsfragmentindex();
final int discoveryFragmentIndex = MainActivity.getDiscoveryfragmentindex();
final int mineFragentIndex = MainActivity.getMinefragmentindex();

switch (mCurIndicator) {
case homeFragmentIndex:
    // do something
    break;
case messageFramentIndex:
    // do something
    break;
case snsFragmentIndex:
    // do something
    break;
case discoveryFragmentIndex:
    // do something
    break;
case mineFragentIndex:
    // do something
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

the Android Studio tell me that `constant expression required`,but I truely use `static fianl int`. Maybe you can help solve this problem,Thanks.

Comment: and mCurIndicator is?

Comment: Does it help if you don't call the get methods, but make the private statics ->  public static and call those

Comment: static cannot be done inside a method

Comment: for which constant or is for mCurIndicator

Comment: mCurIndicator  is  private static int

Comment: use public static instead of private static is useful. But if I want keep these constants in private , how should I do . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Some{
    public static final int HOMEFRAGMENTINDEX = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGEFRAGMENTINDEX = 1;
    public static final int SNSFRAGMENTINDEX = 2;
    public static final int DISCOVERYFRAGMENTINDEX = 3;
    public static final int MINEFRAGMENTINDEX = 4;

}

class AnotherClass{
    void yourMethod(int mCurIndicator){ 
        switch (mCurIndicator) {
            case Some.HOMEFRAGMENTINDEX:
                // do something
                break;
            case Some.MESSAGEFRAGMENTINDEX:
                // do something
                break;
            case Some.SNSFRAGMENTINDEX:
                // do something
                break;
            case Some.DISCOVERYFRAGMENTINDEX:
                // do something
                break;
            case Some.MINEFRAGMENTINDEX:
                // do something
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. But I define these constant in A class,and ues the switch statement in B class,so I want to know how to do this.

Comment: That's why they are public... 'YourClassName.variableName'... give it a shot

Comment: yeah,use public is right. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @ShuaiWang can you, then, accept the answer... :-)